# What is the most efficient way to find all pairs of numbers from a list of integers which add up to a separate given integer?

Tags: math, subset

I had an interview yesterday and was asked to give a method to find all of the pairs of numbers from a list which add up to an integer which is given separate to the list. The list can be infinitely long, but for example:

```
numbers = [11,1,5,27,7,18,2,4,8]
sum = 9

pairs = [(1,8),(5,4),(7,2)]
```

I got as far as sorting the list and eliminating all numbers greater than the `sum` number and then doing two nested for loops to take each index and iterate through the other numbers to check whether they sum up to the given number, but was told that there was a more efficient way of doing it...

I've been trying to figure it out but have nothing, other than doing the nested iteration backwards but that only seems marginally more efficient.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in O(n) time and O(n) auxiliary space; testing for membership of a set takes O(1) time. Since the output also takes up to O(n) space, the auxiliary space should not be a significant issue.

```py
def pairs_sum(numbers, k):
    numbers_set = set(numbers)
    return [(x, y) for x in numbers if (y := k - x) in numbers_set and x < y]
```

Example:

```py
>>> pairs_sum([11, 1, 5, 27, 7, 18, 2, 4, 8], 9)
[(1, 8), (2, 7), (4, 5)]
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how it's O(n) if for each iteration the programme has to check whether y is in the list? Surely that would be an O(n^2) operation?

Comment: It's not checking whether y is in the list; it's checking whether y is in the set.

Comment: @askman Set implementation in Python uses a hash so average case is constant-time for set membership (`in`) operation. Worst-case would be O(n) (similar to non-hashing data structures like list and tuples). So worst-case would be O(n^2) as you've mentioned, but average case (assuming there are no hash collisions) would be O(n*1) = O(n)

Comment: For reference, here is the time complexities of different DS operation implementations in Python:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of a classic and not sure stackoverflow is the right place to ask that kind of question.

1. Sort the list is acsending order
2. Two iterators one starting from the end of the list descending `i1`, one starting from the beginning of the list ascending `i2`
3. Loop

```
while i1 > i2
    if (list[i1] + list[i2] == target)
        store {list[i1], list[i2]) in results pairs
        i1--
        i2++
    else if (list[i1] + list[i2] > target)
        i1--
    else if (list[i1] + list[i2] < target)
        i2++
```

This should be in O(n) with `n` the length of the list if you avoid the sorting algorithm which can be done with a quick sort on average in O(n log n)

**Note:** this algorithm doesn't take into account the case where the input list have several times the same number

Comment: Sorting is not O(n) time.